# jQuery keydown event

Tags: jquery, keydown

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

sqHTML = "<div id=\""+sqStringTemp+"\" class=\"puzzlesquare\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"puzzlesquareinput\" maxlength=\"1\" style=\"text-transform: uppercase;\" onkeypress=\"foo(event)\"/></div>";
jQuery("#gridpuzzleouter").append(sqHTML);

function foo(event) {
    //console.log(event.charCode);
    console.log( String.fromCharCode(event.charCode) );
}

//keydown event
jQuery(".puzzlesquareinput").on('keydown', function() {
    alert("keydown...");
});
```

I have a strange problem with the event not firing. The JavaScript function works fine and prints the key to the console. I am wondering why the jQuery for the keydown event is not firing. There are no errors in my console showing up. The jQuery works with jsFiddle but not on my development machine.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: `sqStringTemp` is not defined. Also, share the jsFiddle url.

Comment: The code is  in context so those are excerpts not the full code which is very much longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work when you wrap it under `jQuery(document).ready...` method.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    sqHTML = "<input type=\"text\" class=\"puzzlesquareinput\" maxlength=\"1\" style=\"text-transform: uppercase;\" onkeypress=\"foo(event)\"/>";
    jQuery("body").append(sqHTML);

    foo = function (event) {
        //console.log(event.charCode);
        console.log(String.fromCharCode(event.charCode));
    }

    //keydown event
    jQuery(".puzzlesquareinput").on('keydown', function () {
        alert("keydown...");
    });
});
```

Check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SKSXJ/1/)

Comment: I believe that is correct and I see the working fiddle however in my code it still does not fire for some reason I have not figured out yet...

Comment: I am wondering at this point if I should make my environment known which is Google Chrome browser on Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

if you have that on `$(document).ready()`, foo() would be undefined... try this instead...

change this code

```
function foo(event) {
        //console.log(event.charCode);
        console.log( String.fromCharCode(event.charCode) );
}
```

to something like this...

```
window.foo = function(event) {
    //console.log(event.charCode);
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(event.charCode));
}
```